# What is the evidence that subjectivity is objectifiable?

Tags: metaphysics, consciousness

[Ray Brassier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_Brassier),  a British Philosopher
in this [interview](http://www.kronos.org.pl/index.php?23151,896) says:

> My claim is not that science has succeeded in explaining consciousness, but only that considerable progress has been made, and that the burden of proof lies with those who insist on denying such progress and who presume to dismiss the attempt as impossible in principle.

What is this progress?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a summary experiment where a computer can [predict a subject's decisions seconds before the subject is conscious of the decision](http://exploringthemind.com/the-mind/brain-scans-can-reveal-your-decisions-7-seconds-before-you-decide).  This experiment seems to make observations on the relationship between physical biological processes and the ultimate subjective, conscious, perception of "having made a decision".

Usually, these experiments are done using real-time f-MRI measurements to detect brain state, and then associating different MRI data patterns with different mental states.

To me, the main issue with these is in identifying the time of "conscious decision" making, to address this different labs have tried to set up different protocols to tease out the exact time of "conscious" decision making, e.g. 
[M. Matsuhashi and M. Hallett "The timing of the conscious intention to move", European Journal of Neuroscience 2008](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1460-9568.2008.06525.x/abstract;jsessionid=10E59E3828792DF80287FC97EC30D887.f04t04) used the idea of when a subject was able to respond to an external stimulus to veto an action.

[Obligatory Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroscience_of_free_will)

I think that, in net, these experiments do represent progress towards understanding the relationship between brain states and mental states, and have significant philosophical implications.

Note: the first linked article is a popularization, but includes a reference to the qualified scientific research.

Comment: This doesn't explain *consciousness* per se. Novelists do a good job of *understanding* the psychology of a character - but this doesn't explain consciousness either. Here they're doing something similar. Its an interesting experiment. Sometimes I procastinate all day about doing something - then I do it. was my decision to do it in the morning when I was procastinating, or in the evening when I did do it?

Comment: @MoziburUllah define consciousness

Comment: @sanmai: Why? Whats makes you think that it is even possible - other than the broad terms by which we recognise it like the word 'consciousness' itself, or 'thought or the 'mental'; If you think its possible - *you* try to define it. Whats your definition?

Comment: @MoziburUllah if you can't define consciousness, then there probably no consciousness

Comment: @sanmai: thats a simple *positivist* attitude. Mathematics deals with *quantified* elements, yet here is Terry Tao, who is a Fields Medal winner (the equivalent of the Nobel Prize) - who asks is it even possible to [define](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.HO/0702396) what is *good* quality mathematics. Besides, if there is no consciousness then murder is not murder - is that a line you can justify?

Comment: @MoziburUllah my point is that if there is no consciousness, then there is nothing to explain; don't you confuse consciousness with sentience, do you?

Comment: @sanmai: In my uneducated mind, sentience is just a synonym of consciousness. In what way do they differ?

Comment: Consciousness is sentience, awareness, subjectivity, the ability to experience or to feel, wakefulness, having a sense of selfhood, and the executive control system of the mind, among other things. There's not a concise definition of consciousness to my knowledge. That's why I asked to define it. And yet you don't have a definition, which inevitably leads to impossibility of explanation. How do you want to explain something you can't even define?

Comment: @sanmai: "There isn't a concise definition of consciousness to my knowledge"; and nor to mine - which is why I didn't bother: I'm quite capable of using my mind without defining it. What makes you think I want to explain it? Is that something that *you* want to do? My initial comment was simply to clarify why this experiemnt, which I have heard reported in the same manner is an example of *rhetoric* for visibility.

Comment: @MoziburUllah You did argue that "it doesn't explain that." I see why you did that now. BTW, I have a questions [that goes in line with yours](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/14014/do-limits-of-human-nature-suggest-that-it-could-be-principally-understood).

Comment: @MoziburUllah (original comment) I'm not saying, nor do I believe that it is required in order to be responsive to this question, that these experiments explain consciousness, rather they indicate some degree of progress in the scientific front.  Maybe I'd liken it to Galeleo's use of the telescope in astronomy.  His observations showed that maybe there is a way to observe the behaviour of the heavens.  In the same way, these experiments are (maybe) the first steps towards probing the mind.  This is (imho) the essence of the quote that prompted the question.

Comment: @dave: for sure; new instruments will always give arise to new possibilities - it would be silly to counter that; and I do think there will be a lot of useful discoveries there. I'm simply resistent to the *rhetoric* that the *essence* of consciousness can be explained through these means; its behaviour - sure; generally I think its due to pervasive popular science journalism - but to be fair to them, and this has often been noted - the sensational sells and they're not in the serious business of serious explanations but in the business of promoting.

Comment: @dave:rereading that quote, I can see why you would say that; and to a certain degree I agree with you; The wiki article also has some useful qualifications which I hadn't noticed before;  but I'd also say that the other side of the debate, when understood correctly have some very good reasons too.

Comment: @MoziburUllah I'd say that  the objection of not getting at _essences_ can be levied against any scientific field.

Comment: @Dave: I'm in agreement with that; Feynman was in agreement with this with regards to the essence of matter (*character of physical law*);